# How can I change the state of subcomponents with React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm testing routing with React ...

If I click on the list, I want the list color to turn orange.

help me plz..

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Nav />
                    <Route path="/counter" component={Counter}/>
                    <Route path="/qna" component={Qna}/>
                </div>  
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

**Nav.js**

```
class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='nav'>
                <span className='brand'>brand</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/counter'>Counter</Link></li>
                    <li className='active'><Link to='/qna'>Qna</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Nav.css**

```
.nav li.active a{
    color: orangered !important;
}
```

**What I want when I click Qna**

[image: What I want when I click Qna]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `activeClassName` prop of React Router.

```js
<li><Link to="/qna" activeClassName="active">Qna</Link></li>
```

Check out [the documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NavLink component, it can automatically add an active class names to the link if URL is matching it. [Doc here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink).

**Nav.js**

```
class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='nav'>
                <span className='brand'>brand</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><NavLink to='/' activeClassName='active'>Home</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/counter' activeClassName='active'>Counter</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/qna' activeClassName='active'>Qna</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Nav.css**

```
.nav li a.active {
    color: orangered !important;
}
```